# Removing previous program installation settings?

Tags: windows-10, installation, uninstall

I have a program that I am installing for work, but I broke a setting and not the program wont launch. I thought no big deal, I'll just reinstall it. Well, that just pulls the same settings that broke the software in the first place. I've tried cleaning the registry after uninstallation, and there isn't anything in appdata that I can find that would automatically pull these settings. Any suggestions on where to look next? I would really rather not nuke the system and start over for one program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installers can write in many areas and file depends on the installer

Firstly if its branded software find uninstaller or remover or ask the software developer email them if they have some remover or uninstallers

Secondly if not possible then tedious work you have to manually trace yourself for marks left  in many folders and files independently or find any tools which can find trace or entries of the software installer in files

Tools which may click

1. Ccleaner registry and files cleaner
2. master cleaner
3. registry cleaners
4. 3rd part uninstallers

Manual ways be careful

1. Registry Regedit find the file name and delete all marks
2. folder or files in

   A. program files folder

   B. windows system system32 (DLL file)

   C. windows config

   D. windows inf folder

   E. users application data

   F.  temporary folder application data
3. easy way to search your partition with *.* having text of software name and carefully finding and deleting  files or opening files and deleting its entries left anywhere in any file

Hope any option will click or work you have to do R&D yourself feel free to ask any more questions